# How to set sidebar `sticky` in Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am developing a sticky sidebar in my Laravel 8 / Bootstrap 5.2. The sidebar is not getting `sticky` with Bootstrap class `sticky-top`. I have tried ti with CSS but its not working.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-xl-3">
    <div class="playbook-sidebar sticky-top">
        <div class="head text-center text-white">
            <h5>Aritae Program Modules</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group rounded-0">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/icons/discovery.svg') }}" alt="icon"> Discovery
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/icons/action.svg') }}" alt="icon"> Focus
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/icons/focus.svg') }}" alt="icon"> Action
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/icons/strategy.svg') }}" alt="icon"> Strategy
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/icons/personal-plan.svg') }}" alt="icon"> Personal Plan
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some solutions I have already tried:

- Making sure there are no console errors
- Setting .col-xl-3 a fixed height

I am unable to understand what is the issue here.
Help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the class `sticky-top` is working perfectly. Issue is that you have used it at wrong place.

See, following code....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    .upper{
        border: solid 1px ;
    }
</style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xl-3 upper ">
    <div class="playbook-sidebar sticky-top">
        <div class="head text-center text-dark">
            <h5>Aritae Program Modules</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group rounded-0">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Discovery
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Focus
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Action
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Strategy
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Personal Plan
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
   

<h1>scroll to see the behaviour</h1>

<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, you got that. actually when you are scrolling, your `playbook-sidebar` class div is sticked to the top of the `upper` div. But `upper` div is still free to move with scroll.

So, just add `sticky-top` class to `upper` div and remove it from `playbook-sidebar` class div. And by doing so your `playback-sidebar` div will stick to the top on scrolling up.

Result will be as per your expectation...
see below..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    .upper{
        border: solid 1px ;
    }
   
</style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xl-3 upper sticky-top">
    <div class="playbook-sidebar">
        <div class="head text-center text-dark">
            <h5>Aritae Program Modules</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group rounded-0">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Discovery
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Focus
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Action
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Strategy
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="" alt="icon"> Personal Plan
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<h1>scroll to see the behaviour</h1>

<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand your point and moved the `sticky-top` class above but its still not sticky for me. Does the right-hand side need to be a fixed height? I tried making it a fix height too although I have a lot of content on right-hand side too.
https://prnt.sc/NqcKbObIsxTu

`<div class="col-xl-3 upper sticky-top">
 <div class="playbook-sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-9">
</div>`